# Get field value

Tags: views, entities

So a basic question. On Drupal 8 I have a views field override using preprocess. I need to get the value of the field but everything I try returns null or an error. I have:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $id = $view->storage->id();
  if ($id == "myfield"){
    $myfieldvalue = $variables['field'];
  }
}
```

I have tried various combinations. I thought **getValue()** might work but no. So far **$variables['field']->original_value** is closest but obviously returns the markup version.

The **$variables** I cannot see the raw value. So question is how do I get it? Do I need to load the node and get it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling **getValue()** of a views field object should work, but you need to provide the row as parameter:

```
$myFieldValue = $variables['field']->getValue($variables['row']);
```

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21FieldPluginBase.php/function/FieldPluginBase%3A%3AgetValue/8.5.x

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with
pass row number and field name

$field_output = $view->style_plugin->getFieldValue(0, 'field_custom_text');